# MySQL UNION with WHERE

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following 2 tables 
tableA a (id, name, surname, program, date)
tableB b (id, aid, name, surname, extracard)
with tableA.id = tableB.aid (1 to n relationship)

```
Sample data for tableA:
| ID | NAME  | SURNAME | PROGRAM |   DATE    |  EXPIRES  |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | TOM   | JONES   | 1,2,3   | 12/8/2012 | 12/8/2013 |
| 2  | JAMIE | OLIVER  | 4,5,6   | 15/8/2012 | 15/8/2013 |

Sample data for tableB:
| ID | AID | NAME  | SURNAME | CARD |
-------------------------------------
| 1  |  1  | ANNE  | JONES   |  1   |
| 2  |  1  | JACK  | BOWER   |  0   |
| 3  |  2  | KATE  | PERRY   |  1   |
| 4  |  2  | JOHN  | DOE     |  0   |
| 5  |  2  | HARRY | POTTER  |  0   |
```

In the results, each member of tableB should have all values (program, date, expires, etc...) from tableA and display only the name, surname from tableB **in the same column** (coalesce??). Also, I need to use a between clause for a.id between (%id1 and %id2) and also a WHERE statement for selecting  rows where tableB.card=1

```
| a.ID | NAME  | SURNAME | PROGRAM |   DATE    |  EXPIRES  |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   | TOM   | JONES   | 1,2,3   | 12/8/2012 | 12/8/2013 |
|  1   | ANNE  | JONES   | 1,2,3   | 12/8/2012 | 12/8/2013 |
|  2   | JAMIE | OLIVER  | 4,5,6   | 15/8/2012 | 15/8/2013 |
|  2   | KATE  | PERRY   | 4,5,6   | 15/8/2012 | 15/8/2013 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
   ( (SELECT a.id ,a.name,a.surname,a.program,a.date,a.expires 
    from tableA a left outer join tableB b 
    on b.aid=a.id 
    where b.card=1 and (a.id between '1' and '2'))
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT a.id ,b.name,b.surname,a.program,a.date,a.expires 
    from tableA a left outer join tableB b 
    on b.aid=a.id 
    where b.card=1 and (a.id between '1' and '2'))) t
    ORDER BY id
```

EDITED:
Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8227/1

Comment: Thanks but this is a simple join that returns name, surname in separate columns, where I need them in the same column.

Comment: Edited the answer. This should be what you looking for.

Comment: Note that program, date and expires appear in all results although they are only to be found in tableA. I assume we need COALESCE somewhere in there but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Meaning you do not want to use UNION?

Comment: Not sure. Please look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee9d7/1 and notice the rows from tableA that repeat themselves.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee9d7/2 change to UNION instead of UNION ALL. is that your desired result?

Comment: Yes, thank you so very much!! I have been headaching over this one for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for -

```
(SELECT a.id, name, surname, program, date, expires FROM tableA a WHERE a.id BETWEEN '%id1' and '%id2')
UNION
(SELECT a.id, b.name, b.surname, program, date, expires FROM tableB b LEFT JOIN tableA a ON b.aid=a.id WHERE b.card=1 AND (a.id between '%id1' and '%id2') )
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(select a.ID,a.NAME,a.SURNAME,a.PROGRAM,a.DATE,a.EXPIRES from tableA a where ...)    
Union All    
(select a2.ID,b.NAME,b.SURNAME,a2.PROGRAM,a2.DATE,a2.EXPIRES from tableB b 
 left join tableA a2 on b.aid = a2.id where ...);
```

You can choose `left/inner join` as per your need and `where` condition too with `between` clause like.. `where id between 2 and 8` or `where id > 2 and id < 8`.

Comment: TableB doesnt have columns date, expires, those are only in TableA but should appear in rows from TableB as well. (Coalesce?)

Comment: yes, tableb has a join with tablea so those column value for rows will be carried form tablea as per the join.